# DjangoREST vs ExpressJS , which 1 should I choose to build REST API?

Tags: python, node.js, django, express, django-rest-framework

I want to build **REST API** *(or GraphQL API)* which I want to connect with **Angular (2+)** to build some nice web application.
Which framework should I choose to get started with and why? **DjangoREST or ExpressJS** ?
Which one of them is easier to get connected with front-end frameworks?
I know ***python*** as well as ***JavaScript***. I also have experience with django as well as some JavaScript front-end frameworks like Angular. So, it wouldn't be that difficult to get started with *nodejs* or either of them.
Which of then is ***easier*** and ***better***?

Answer (score 26):

> **In short, Django for quick development and Express for full-stack,
>   scalable solutions.**

1. Django provides better, easier security without as much experience. In the case of Express, it takes **so much experience and confidence** to get the same security from Node.JS
2. Django uses the MVT (**Model View Template**) design pattern and Express uses **event-driven programming** in which the entire architecture is driven by “events” or user choices. MVT is excellent for server-side development, on the other hand, event-driven programming is rather than separating client and server sides.
3. Django uses an **in-house template system**, so you won't hang to choosing the right one. With Express, a fully open system you may spend a lot amount of time to choose the perfect one for you.
4. Django is more structured to work around. It tells you **how to do** whereas express gives you the flexibility **to do it in your way**. For example, you need to use Django's ORM to interact with the database, but in the case of Express, you can choose any tool you like.
5. **Express gives you freedom**. So, if you’re experienced, there is a space to create whatever you want from scratch. Django gives you a lot of solutions with a vast template and library system, which is **great for productivity but not enough for the vision**.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation but I still have some doubt. In point no. 3 you are telling about in templates. But I don't want to use Django templates insted I would like to integrate it with Angular which I still don't know how to do as I can't find any documentation guiding how to do it. If you know how to do this please share or please upload link to any resource.

Comment: I think this [article will help you](https://medium.com/swlh/django-angular-4-a-powerful-web-application-60b6fb39ef34) to get started the integration of both of them. If you have any interest in `React` instead of `Angular`, you'll found many useful video tutorial on youtube about **Django and React**, even I also subscribe to one channel which I found very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't need Django templates, you need to look into using **Django REST Framework** https://www.django-rest-framework.org as opposed to just plain Django. It lets you easily, and quickly, make REST API's that Angular, or any other front-end can consume.

Comment: This is a very opinative question. But saying that "express gives you freedom" is such a vague answer. Assembly might also give you a lot of freedom but it doesn't mean anything :p

Comment: Hey @EnzoDtz, obviously, each language has some pros and cons, but the question was about Django REST vs ExpressJS. Is it fair to compare with assembly then?